# How to set shared-session-context true by default

Tags: maven, websphere-liberty, sessioncontext

I've a **Maven EAR** with some modules that need to share the session context.
So when I run it on **Liberty Server** (on Eclipse) I've to add in the "Server Configuration" the application extension and set the `shared-session-context` flag to true.

I guess how can I set it by default, maybe in the pom.xml? I can find any information about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended practice is to have in your source repo `server.xml` that is required for your application, and have all the required settings there. Then your maven build creates also Liberty server with your config and deploys app there.

If you dont want to store that in the server config file, you can add `ibm-application-ext.xml` file to your `EAR/META-INF` folder, with shared session enabled like this:

`ibm-application-ext.xml` contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-ext xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-ext_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1">

    <shared-session-context value="true"/>
</application-ext>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've added the `ibm-application-ext.xml` in `myproject/EarContent/META-INF/` and in the `pom.xml` I've `<earSourceIncludes>**/META-INF/ibm-application-*.xml</earSourceIncludes>`, any idea?

Comment: @Alessandro - any idea on what? Does your generated ear contains that META-INF folder with the ibm-application-ext.xml  file?

Comment: Well, I see... No, my ear doesn't contain that file.

Comment: @Alessandro in that case you need to fix your pom file to correctly include that xml file so it is in the target ear. Maybe it is in wrong location.

Comment: Well, I did it using `earSourceIncludes`... Thank you